# android image transition

Tags: android, image, transition, image-resizing

1. What is the best way in android to make animation for image transition between images?
2. what is the best way to re-size the image to fit the screen?

thanks to all

Comment: Do you want to resize on-the-fly, or offline?

Comment: Do you want to know which desktop tool is best to prepare resized images for use on the phone as-is, or do you want to perform the resizing on the phone?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos i want to do it on the phone ...plz

Answer (score 0):

1. use viewflipper. maybe not the best but it really works if you wanna customize animation in view transition.
2. set the image as the background of imageview or some layout.